# How to check if core files have changed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, diff

I am working on a project in Bootstrap 4. I suspect that core file have been disturbed/changed by other developers and want to prove if i am right or wrong. How can i compare to both, as it is a huge framework.

Comment: Redownload the Bootstrap4 source files you are using and make a diff (you can diff whole directories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Bootstrap core files are in `dir1/` and you are on linux (or have access to a terminal, i.e. git shell).

1. Download the Bootstrap4 core files again into `dir2/` next to `dir1`
2. Navigate to the parent directory of `dir1` and `dir2` in your terminal
3. run a diff i.e.: `$ diff -r dir1/ dir2/`
4. Check the output for differences

Comment: unfortunately i am on windows.

Comment: windows 10 power shell?

Comment: when i do `diff -r dist/dist2/` it get output saying  `cmdlet Compare-Object
Supply values for the
DifferenceObject[0]:` asking me to enter. What to enter?

Comment: See [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/5598/how-do-i-diff-two-text-files-in-windows-powershell) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877238/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-diff-command).

Comment: Alternatively you can install the [git shell](https://git-for-windows.github.io) on windows

Comment: I installed git for windows and it says this `$ diff -r dist/dist2/
diff: missing operand after 'dist/dist2/'
`

Comment: There need to be a space between the two directories

Comment: that is long files of css and scss. How am i able to check what i need to check. Did it output everything?

Comment: Ok try `diff -rq dist/ dist2/` . The `q` Shows only the differences

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if you are using version control software (git?). If you don't use it it might be hard to show that change.

Comment: No i am not, but i can push the files, though there are tons

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Andreas's answer, you can diff in a number of ways.

**$ Diff**

Most popular is likely shell/terminal diff as mentioned in Andrea's answer.

**GitHub**

You could also use version control tools, upload each as a branch, and see the diff in GitHub.

**Software**

There's also a number of installable software. I often use [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare directories of photos to see if they've been edited.