# Comparing two versions of same CSV files in Python - getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a Python script that will help me and my colleagues comparing the versions of the same .csv file.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = (r'C:\Jarek S\results_old.csv')
file2 = (r'C:\Jarek S\results_new.csv')
file3 = (r'C:\Jarek S\results_diff.csv')

cols_to_show = ['emp_id', 'Onbr', 'Measure', 'Status', 'Start', 'End', 'SM', 'Rev',
   'PY', 'table', 'terr_id', 'first_nm', 'last_nm', 'job_cd',
   'job_title_nm', 'ctry_cd', 'District', 'Fac_nm']

old = pd.read_csv(file1)
new = pd.read_csv(file2)


def report_diff(x):
return x[0] if x[1] == x[0] else '{0} --> {1}'.format(*x)

#old.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
#new.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

old['version'] = 'old'
new['version'] = 'new'

full_set = pd.concat([old, new], ignore_index=True)

changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show, keep='last')

dupe_emp_ids = changes.set_index('emp_id').index.get_duplicates()

dupes = changes[changes['emp_id'].isin(dupe_emp_ids)]

change_new = dupes[(dupes['version'] == 'new')]
change_old = dupes[(dupes['version'] == 'old')]

change_new = change_new.drop(['version'], axis=1)
change_old = change_old.drop(['version'], axis=1)

change_new.set_index('emp_id', inplace=True)
change_old.set_index('emp_id', inplace=True)

diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old, df2=change_new))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)

changes['duplicate'] = changes['emp_id'].isin(dupe_emp_ids)
removed_emp_ids = changes[(changes['duplicate'] == False) & (changes['version'] == 'old')]
removed_emp_ids.set_index('emp_id', inplace=True)

new_emp_id_set = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_show)

new_emp_id_set['duplicate'] = new_emp_id_set['emp_id'].isin(dupe_emp_ids)

added_emp_ids = new_emp_id_set[(new_emp_id_set['duplicate'] == False) & (new_emp_id_set['version'] == 'new')]
added_emp_ids.set_index('emp_id', inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([diff_output, removed_emp_ids, added_emp_ids], keys=('changed', 'removed', 'added'))
df[cols_to_show].to_csv(file3)
```

What I am trying to do here is compare the files using the column emp_nbr as a reference. Unfortunately, I am relatively new to the python scripting and the only thing I'm getting is the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7c071d4996a5> in <module>()
----> 1 diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old, df2=change_new))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py in __init__(self, data, items, major_axis, minor_axis, copy, dtype)
152 
153         self._init_data(data=data, items=items, major_axis=major_axis,
--> 154                         minor_axis=minor_axis, copy=copy, dtype=dtype)
155 
156     def _init_data(self, data, copy, dtype, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py in _init_data(self, data, copy, dtype, **kwargs)
177             mgr = data
178         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 179             mgr = self._init_dict(data, passed_axes, dtype=dtype)
180             copy = False
181             dtype = None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py in _init_dict(self, data, axes, dtype)
214         # extract axis for remaining axes & create the slicemap
215         raxes = [self._extract_axis(self, data, axis=i) if a is None else a
--> 216                  for i, a in enumerate(axes)]
217         raxes_sm = self._extract_axes_for_slice(self, raxes)
218 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
214         # extract axis for remaining axes & create the slicemap
215         raxes = [self._extract_axis(self, data, axis=i) if a is None else a
--> 216                  for i, a in enumerate(axes)]
217         raxes_sm = self._extract_axes_for_slice(self, raxes)
218 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py in _extract_axis(self, data, axis, intersect)
1504             # 2. the indices are not aligned.
1505             index = _get_objs_combined_axis(data.values(), axis=axis,
-> 1506                                             intersect=intersect, sort=None)
1507 
1508         if have_raw_arrays:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py in _get_objs_combined_axis(objs, intersect, axis, sort)
 52                  if hasattr(obj, '_get_axis')]
 53     if obs_idxes:
---> 54         return _get_combined_index(obs_idxes, intersect=intersect, sort=sort)
 55 
 56 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py in _get_combined_index(indexes, intersect, sort)
 67             index = index.intersection(other)
 68     else:
---> 69         index = _union_indexes(indexes, sort=sort)
 70         index = _ensure_index(index)
 71 

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py in _union_indexes(indexes, sort)
105         else:
106             for other in indexes[1:]:
--> 107                 result = result.union(other)
108             return result
109     elif kind == 'array':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in union(self, other)
2766                 result.extend([x for x in rvals if x not in value_set])
2767         else:
-> 2768             indexer = self.get_indexer(other)
2769             indexer, = (indexer == -1).nonzero()
2770 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
3227 
3228         if not self.is_unique:
 -> 3229             raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
3230                                     ' valued Index objects')
3231 

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I've tried some modifications, but that doesn't help me at all. Can you please help me with the error below? Or at least point to the direction that'll help me to create a script that will compare two .csv files and save the result in the third file?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using "diff" on Linux or the windows equivalent ([What is the Windows equivalent of the diff command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877238/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-diff-command)) to achieve this result. It should be a lot easier to just use the already implemented system level functions and pass the files as arguments to them.