# markdown github - how to do green code added git and red code deleted in README?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

how to do this, coloring lines (like git)?

[image]

here is an example where it is used: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/7716

in markdown, in GitHub readme.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

add the symbol `+` and `-` (with `diff` syntax in markdown)

| symbol | `+` | `-` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | Addition | Deletion |
| color | Green | Red |
| what it does do? | code that being added or changed code | code that being deleted or removed |

### how to write it in MD?

***```diff***

***-oldText***

***+newText***

***```***

### how it will look?

[image]

### real example to copy and paste.

see here, I created a gist for you: https://gist.github.com/Laaouatni/1f0825dc0c531eb7cfb49ecc9560094c (click raw to copy code)

---

now you will be asking me,

### why `diff` in particular?

by just going to google and searching: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+diff+means+linux

[image]

the first thing that came to my mind is the command `diff`, and I tried to search if diff is actually used in markdown, and it turns out that the info is true so it was real.

so use `diff` instead of javascript/python, or whatever...

https://gist.github.com/Laaouatni/1f0825dc0c531eb7cfb49ecc9560094c (click raw to copy code)

---

#### do I manually need to add the symbols?

I always suggest little lines... so it will be easier for you to manually add the symbols.

but if you have a lot of lines,

then you don't have to manually add `+` and `-`,

since if you have Linux just use the `diff` command, and will return you the text that you can copy and paste to GitHub.

by searching for differences in 2 files.

the command is something like this:

```
diff example1.txt example2.txt
```

> if you are on windows, I am not pretty sure it will work or not, but try to see it here: [What is the Windows equivalent of the diff command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877238/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-diff-command), but yeah if it is only for 2 or maximum 10 lines I think writing manually can be time-saving... but you have entire pieces of code then do your research if you think it will worth the time.

---

### attention:

by using a `diff` language name, now you can have this special design.

also, this works only in GitHub,

and you can't color highlight for a specified language like *python* or *javascript* for example...

example: [image] there isn't any color highlighting

> so use it when necessary to point out a breaking change for example.

---