# diff -r for windows?

Tags: windows, diff

To find differences in files between two directory structures I usually run

```
diff -r dir1/ dir2/
```

I'm burdened with Windows - is there any way to do this easily Windows or should I just get Cygwin?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011269/how-to-do-diff-r-of-unix-in-windows-cmd-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a tool called FreeFileSync. As the name implies it's free :) It does a great job of visually comparing directories and does not move any files unless you tell it to sync.

It also has a portable version so you do not need to install it.

[FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)

Comment: I ended up going for cygwin and the old fashioned diff -r but awareness for this tool should get more visibility - it is cool.

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) does a pretty good job. It isn't free though (but it is nagware, if I recall).

You can use cygwin or mingw, but these are very slow compared to the unix variants, I believe due to the (possibly intentionally) crippled posix implementation on windows.

Answer (score 0):

if you have windiff you can try:

```
 windiff -T dir1 dir2
```

also, you can download the Gnu utils for windows to run to traditional Unix diff (with no Cygwin required)

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/